# jcifs.smb.SmbException: Access is Denied. exception for smb directories

Tags: java, android, samba, cifs, jcifs

In the below code statement:

```
SmbFileInputStream din==new SmbFileInputStream(src);
```

I am trying to create a SmbFileInputStream object. This will works fine if SmbFile 'src' is a file, but if 'src' is a smb Directory then it throws exception:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Access is Denied.
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:622)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:722)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:262)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:785)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:1009)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1026)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.<init>(SmbFileInputStream.java:73)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.<init>(SmbFileInputStream.java:65)
at testhelp.main(testhelp.java:25)
```

What is wrong with this code? or where am I going wrong?

Hi please check this code:

```
case DOWNLOAD2:

/*This code snippet is used to download a file/folder from smb nETWORK to android sd card.
when I run this code its throwing some exception. It have commented where ever necessary. rest of the code is self
explanatory. So please go through the code and please tell why this exception is thrown.
IF POSSIBLE PLEASE ADD A PROGRESS BAR WHICH SHOULD HELP USER SAYING SOME WORK IS GOING ON.
I have tried including a progress bar, but its not working. I ve read some materials related to this,
but every thing makes use threads. I am not that good at threads. So is it possible to include a progess bar,
without using threads?If possible please help me to do it.
And this code is working file for smb files, I dont know why its throwing exception in case of directories.
Please see why this is throwing exception..
So please see that the modified code contains:
a)no exceptions
b)a progress bar(more specifically a horizontal bar)*/

/*exception thrown:
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Access is Denied.
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:622)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:722)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:262)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:785)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:1009)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1026)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.<init>(SmbFileInputStream.java:73)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.<init>(SmbFileInputStream.java:65)
at testhelp.main(testhelp.java:25)*/


StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()); 
//if sd card is mounted then only this operation occur:
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
    //object.getCount() gets the number of objects in list view
    for(int i=0;i<object.getCount();i++)
    {
        //for each object in list view, if it is checked:
        if(object.getter(i)==true)
        {
            SmbFileInputStream din=null;
            FileOutputStream dout=null;
            try 
            {
                //I have used a hash table, which maps list view name with smb object
                SmbFile src=map.get(object.getItem(i));
                long blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
                long freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocks()*blockSize;
                long diff=freeSize-src.length();
                boolean can=false;
                if(!(diff<0))
                {
                    can=true;
                }
                if(!src.isHidden() && can)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(src.isFile())
                        {
                            din=new SmbFileInputStream(src);
                            dout=new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+src.getName());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            din=new SmbFileInputStream(src);
                            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+src.getName()); // ADDED
                            outputFile.mkdirs(); // ADDED
                            dout=new FileOutputStream(outputFile); // CHANGED
                        }
                        int c;
                        while((c=din.read())!=-1)
                        {
                            dout.write(c);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (din != null) 
                        {
                            din.close();
                        }
                        if (dout != null) 
                        {
                            dout.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,src.getName()+" cannot be downloaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"DOWNLOAD FAILED--IO EXCEPTION\n"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"DOWNLOAD FAILED--NO SD CARD FOUND",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create an `SmbFileInputStream` for a directory, because you can't read/write directly to the directory object. A directory doesn't have any content, at least not in the same way that a file has content.

If you're trying to read the contents of a directory, you should probably be using `SmbFile` instead (for example, use the `listFiles()` method). The `SmbFileInputStream` object is only for reading information from a file.

To write a file to a directory, do this...

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/filename.txt");
file.mkdirs(); // this creates all the directories that are missing
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream (file);
// now write the file data
os.write(...);
```

In your code, change the following few lines...

```
   try
   {
    din=new SmbFileInputStream(src);
    dout=new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+src.getName());
    int c;
    while((c=din.read())!=-1)
```

To this...

```
   try
   {
    din=new SmbFileInputStream(src);

    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+src.getName()); // ADDED
    outputFile.mkdirs(); // ADDED

    dout=new FileOutputStream(outputFile); // CHANGED
    int c;
    while((c=din.read())!=-1)
```

Also change the following...

```
if(src.isFile()){
    din=new SmbFileInputStream(src);
    //dout=new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+src.getName());// REMOVE THIS LINE
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+src.getName()); // ADDED
    outputFile.mkdirs();  // ADDED
    dout=new FileOutputStream(outputFile);  // ADDED
}
else {
    //din=new SmbFileInputStream(src); // REMOVE THIS LINE
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+src.getName());
    outputFile.mkdirs(); 
    //dout=new FileOutputStream(outputFile); // REMOVE THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: Then how can i copy directories to sd card of my android phone? Because  if i use copyTo() method of SmbFile class in jcifs package, i cannot create android's destination file (that is "/mnt/sdcard/") as smbFile object. So how to implement directory copying?

Comment: You would need to create all the directories first using `new SmbFile(file).mkdirs()`, then open a `SmbFileInputStream` to write the file to it. See my edited code.

Comment: Hey do i need to create directories in sd card? becos before i use FileOutputStream to write to sd card, the above exception is thrown..

Comment: Yes, you will need to create the directories before you can write files to them. If you're trying to use normal File classes like `FileOutputStream`, you can use `new File(filename).mkdirs()` before the `FileOutputStream` to create all the destination directories too. I have edited my answer again to use this instead.

Comment: Hi WATTO, please see "Hi please check this code:" above and please tell me where should i add ur explaination..or please edit my code if possible..

Comment: I have edited my answer to show where you should make the change.

Comment: hey even after including the above changes u ve made, i am getting the same exception. what should i do?

Comment: hi WATTO, i included ur changes, and further changed my code. please see my edited code.

Comment: I have added further changed - see the last piece of code in my edited answer.

Comment: Hey for file, u r creating directory in sd card, why u r doing that?

Comment: hi, WATTO please see my code, i have commented where ever necessary. It will clearly depicts the purpose of code

Comment: You've still got the code `din=new SmbFileInputStream(src);` when you're processing a directory. This is definitely causing a problem - you can't open an `InputStream` of any type to a directory object. You need to remove this from the *directory* part of your `if-else` statement

Comment: Thanks WATTO, i solved the problem by recursively creating directories and copying files..