# Jcfis jcifs.smb.SmbException: Access is denied

Tags: jcifs

i have a problem when i try to move a file to a shared folder in win xp.

My code is the next

```
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;;

public class UnidadRed {

//public static void main(File enviado) throws Exception {
public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
    String enviado = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\u2d8301\\Escritorio\\probando\\estadisticas.txt";
    String salida = "smb://172.22.224.64/Color";

    //Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", "NTDOMAIN");
    Config.setProperty( "jcifs.smb.client.username", "name");
    Config.setProperty( "jcifs.smb.client.password", "password");
    //Config.setProperty( "jcifs.netbios.wins", "172.22.224.64");
    System.out.println("Copiando fichero ''" + enviado + "'' a ''" +salida + "''");


    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(enviado);
        SmbFileOutputStream out = new SmbFileOutputStream(salida);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 16];
        int len, total=0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
                total+=len;
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println(total + " bytes copiados.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

I try to move a txt to a folder that will print automatically the file, when i execute appears the next failures:

```
Copiando fichero ''C:\Documents and Settings\u2d8301\Escritorio\probando    \estadisticas.txt'' a ''smb://172.22.224.64/Color''
    jcifs.smb.SmbException: Access is denied.
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:989)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:82)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:54)
at apliSep.UnidadRed.main(UnidadRed.java:25)
```

I put correctly the name and password, because if a try a non valid login/password apperas a different message.

The my question is:

**Is it neccesary other parametres in config.setProperty?**

Thank you for all.

Comment: I need help, i can not solve the problem yet. Perhaps it is a problem of the configuration of the shared folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433119/jcifs-smb-smbexception-access-is-denied-exception-for-smb-directories).You can't create a SmbFileInputStream for a directory, so take a look at the link and change SmbFileInputStream for SmbFile.

Comment: I am trying to do the inverse operation, i try to put a file in a share folder. The code you referenced me are the inverse operation, i think that probably i can create a SmbFileInputStream because i try to save information in that folder, and i will not need to obtein files in that folder.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, didn't see that, sorry. I heard about some bugs relating "access is denied" with jcifs. What version are you currently using?

Comment: Hi again i am using the version 1.3.17.